# Upload a zip file for translation in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a zip file containing several .CATPART, .CATDRAWING and one main .CATPRODUCT file. is it possible to upload all the files ( as a zip) and get the model translated ? and possibility of setting the main file. And is  this [tutorial](https://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/07/translate-referenced-files-by-derivative-api.html) still valid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating a ZIP file with multiple designs in it is possible. See [this tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-zip-to-stl/), specifically [task #3 step #1](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-zip-to-stl/task3-translate-source-file/#step-1-start-a-translation-job).

Note however that the .CATDRAWING may not be processed during the conversion. See the list of [supported translations](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/).